# How to generate an integer unique id in a multi-user application without duplication in C#/SqlServer?

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Scenario**

I want to generate a unique integer key (not a database primary key) by extracting max() and incrementing it by one. Then I want to use that integer key for insert/update operations in one or more tables. I prefer to do this in C# code but if there's no other option then I could go for SQL batch statements or inside a stored procedure etc as well.

**Question**

Since multiple users can be doing this at the same time, how do I ensure that no two users get the same max()?

**Sample pseudocode**
Let's say there are two tables - Employee (Columns: EmpId, BatchId, Name) and MiscData (Columns: EmpId, BatchId).

Below is the C# inspired pseudocode that shows one implementation of this scenario -

```
void DoOperation(int empId, string[] names)
{
    int maxBatchId = repository.GetMaxBatchId(); //GetMaxBatchId() basically executes select max(BatchId) from Employee
    maxBatchId++;
    foreach(string name in names)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery("insert into Employee values (" + maxBatchId + ", '" + name + "')");
    command.ExecuteNonQuery("insert into MiscData select EmpId, " + maxBatchId + " where EmpId = " + empId);
}
```

The method DoOperation above can be doing whatever database operations based on the value of maxBatchId + 1.

If more than one users run DoOperation(...) at the same time, they're likely to get exactly same maxBatchId. How do I ensure that only a single instance of this method can run at one time?

Comment: They are called "transactions". Do note that you need to do `select`and `update` in the same transaction

Comment: I would suggest doing the Insert and Select in the same Executing command.. put the SQL in a Stored Procedure and do it that way..

Comment: Solution for sql 2008 is here - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104884/can-i-simulate-a-sequence-in-pre-2012-sql-server-with-separate-identity-column. For SQL 2012 just use `sequence`.

Comment: Got it. So, there's no real way to do this in C# code then? Doing all of it in the db will require migrating a bunch of business logic (all that will go in the DoOperation part) from C# to SQL. I was wondering if there's some pattern or something that can be applied to have the same effect as that of database transactions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sequence in SQL Server

```
CREATE SEQUENCE testseq  
START WITH 1  
INCREMENT BY 1 ;  

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR testseq
```

Comment: Thanks. It'll help create sequential integers but does it help with the isolation problem (more than one readers reading the same database table value)?

Answer (score 0):

**I cannot use sequence in SQL server because I cannot have gaps in the numbers due to regulatory rules.**

This is an old post but while I was reading this to find an answer I thought of a different way that might actually work and posting it here to help others.

If you create a new column in the table and set the identity insert to true and 1,1 when you save the record it will be unique.

BUT you may not be able to modify the database table as it may affect other areas...

So what you can do is create a new table with three fields:  ID, Username, CurrentDateTime.

The ID field is incrementing(1,1)

When you want a unique ID simply add a record to that table with the current date and time and the username which will generate you a unique ID and you can

Select Top 1 ID where UserName = XXX order by DateTime Desc

That will give you that users last entry in this table which you can use as your unique integer key

Pros:

1. Unique identifier that will never duplicate in a multi-user
   environment
2. If you have records already created you can insert them
   into this table after the fact and start using this method.

Cons: An extra table

The extra table will take almost no space in your database and any old systems won't be affected by this new table.   New systems might complain that the table should not exist and of course this needs to be tested.